# Reaming Time view

Tags: java, android

Hello i am new in android development and i need help in my app to view the remaining time like this in the txt_remaining of the next time event in the a above textview in the text view i got alaways "four" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bjUy.png)

```
public void getTime() {

    // Retrive lat, lng using location API
    double latitude = 31.952162;
    double longitude = 35.233154;
    double timezone = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()
            .getOffset(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()))
            / (1000 * 60 * 60);
    PrayTime prayers = new PrayTime();

    prayers.setTimeFormat(prayers.Time24);
    prayers.setCalcMethod(prayers.Makkah);
    prayers.setAsrJuristic(prayers.Shafii);
    prayers.setAdjustHighLats(prayers.AngleBased);
    int[] offsets = {3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 7}; // {Fajr,Sunrise,Dhuhr,Asr,Sunset,Maghrib,Isha}
    prayers.tune(offsets);

    Date now = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);

    ArrayList<String> prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude,
            longitude, timezone);
    ArrayList<String> prayerNames = prayers.getTimeNames();
    String[] mylistName = new String[prayerNames.size()];
    mylistName = prayerNames.toArray(mylistName);

    String[] mylistTime = new String[prayerTimes.size()];
    mylistTime = prayerTimes.toArray(mylistTime);

    final TextView txt_remaing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_time_view);


    final String[] finalMylistTime = mylistTime;


          LocalTime[] myTimes = new LocalTime[] {

                    LocalTime.parse(finalMylistTime[0],TIME_FORMATTER), // fajer
                    LocalTime.parse(finalMylistTime[2],TIME_FORMATTER), // th
                    LocalTime.parse(finalMylistTime[3],TIME_FORMATTER), // asser
                    LocalTime.parse(finalMylistTime[4],TIME_FORMATTER), // magreb
                    LocalTime.parse(finalMylistTime[6],TIME_FORMATTER) // ishaa


            };
               LocalTime time  = LocalTime.now();

                 if (time.isBefore(myTimes[1]))
                      {
                       txt_remaing.setText("one");
                      }

                 if (time.isBefore(myTimes[2]))
                     {
                          txt_remaing.setText("two");
                     }
                 if (time.isBefore(myTimes[3]))
                 {
                     txt_remaing.setText("three");

                 }
                 if (time.isBefore(myTimes[4]))
                 {
                     txt_remaing.setText("four");
                 }




    list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, mylistName, mylistTime);

    System.out.println("adapter => " + lviewAdapter.getCount());

    list_view.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
}
```

Comment: If you can use the Java 8 java.time library (not sure if this is available in Android) then the `until` method of the `LocalDateTime` class is the obvious thing to use.  There'll be three steps - (1) identify which prayer time (or sunrise) is next, (2) figure out how many seconds remain, (3) format this as hours, minutes and seconds.  Oh, and the word is "remaining", not "reaming" (which means something else).

Comment: Thank you @dawood-ibn-kareem can you tell me how to identify which prayer time is next .

Comment: Assuming you've already calculated all six times (the five prayer times plus sunrise), and assuming ishaa occurs before midnight (which might not be true in mid-summer, in very high latitudes); the simplest thing is probably just to work through the times in order, comparing each one to the current time.  The first one you come to that's after the current time is the one you want.  If you don't find one that's after the current time, then the next prayer time is fajr tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you again @DawoodibnKareem i do it by if  but i always got the "four"

Comment: The second, third and fourth `if` statements need to be `else if` instead.

Comment: Thank you @DawoodibnKareem i hope if you see my app in amazon store https://www.amazon.com/E-School-PrayerTimes-%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9/dp/B0733ZSHG2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1498629568&sr=8-1&keywords=Prayers+Time+%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AA+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9